# Unable to fetch events using Ethers js

Tags: ethers.js, events, event-handling

I am trying to fetch two events from a contract on Goerli. One of them is being fetched correctly but the other one doesn't.

The working one :

```
 let eventFilter = Core.filters.AddChannel();//Core is the contract instance, and it is correctly initialized. 
  let events = await Core.queryFilter(eventFilter);
  console.log(`Total ${events.length} Add events found `);
```

Not working :

```
let Filter = Core.filters.UpdateChannel();
 let events = await Core.queryFilter(Filter);

 console.log(`Total ${events.length} update events found`);
```

here is the contract address : [0x23346b732d56d34ec4e890419fbfb8548216a799](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x23346b732d56d34ec4e890419fbfb8548216a799#events)

The later one is printing an empty array, there is no error popping up either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad.

The deployed contract was an old contract, containing only two parameters in the event, but the instance I was creating had three parameters, producing a wrong filter for the event.

Answer (score 1):

The contract hasn't emitted that event yet. The only functions called so far is the `createChannel`. Try calling `updateChannelMeta` which emits the `UpdateChannel` event.

Comment: If you filter the events with several block numbers, you'll notice it has emitted the event. The `updateChannelMeta` tx is there, if you check txs more than 30 days old.